# Laravel: unable to build multiple orWhere query with laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to make this query with laravel query builder but i did not understand how i can do this:

**Query**

```
select * from `data_table_1486794412` where (`column_2` = '2014' or `column_2` = '2015') and (`column_1` = 'GNDU')
```

**My Code is:**

```
$dbObj =  DB::table($datatableName->dataset_table);
$dbObj->orWhere('column_2','2015');
$dbObj->orWhere('column_2','2015');
$dbObj->where(array('column_1','GNDU'));
```

**Laravel Generating Query:**

```
select * from `data_table_1486794412` where `column_2` = ? or `column_2` = ? and (`column_1` = ?)
```

**My Table**

[image: data_table_1486794412]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to group WHERE clauses so that they're surrounded by brackets you need to pass a callback to **where()** call.

The following code should do the trick:

```
$dbObj =  DB::table($datatableName->dataset_table);
$column1 = 2015;
$column2 = 2016;    

$dbObj->where(function($query) use ($column1, $column2) {
  $query->orWhere('column_1',$column1);
  $query->orWhere('column_2',$column2);
});
$dbObj->where(array('column_1','GNDU'));
```

Comment: can we pass extra params with anonymous function? wirth `$query,$extra`

Comment: what params do you want to pass?

Comment: that values of each columns are coming from separate var. means 2015 and 2014

Comment: I've added an example on how you could pass values to the calback

Answer (score 0):

i think that's work

```
$dbObj =  DB::table($datatableName->dataset_table);
$dbObj->orWhere('column_2','2015')->orWhere('column_2','2015')->where(array('column_1','GNDU'))
```

Comment: i am using `orWhere` in loop. can you please tell how i can use it in loop..because `2014` and `2015` are coming in form of `array`

Answer (score 0):

i am using orWhere in loop. can you please tell how i can use it in loop..because 2014 and 2015 are coming in form of array.

You can use whereIn rather than a loop, where you can pass in an array:

```
$dbObj =  DB::table($datatableName->dataset_table);
$dbObj->where('column_1', 'GNDU')->whereIn('column_2', $yourArray)->get();
```